# Convert a one dimensional array into an array of objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've flattened an array like this: `let playerPool = [...new Set(array.flat(1))];`
Which has an output like this: `["Howard Bell", "Matt Blair", "Dave Custer"]`

How can I turn this into an array of objects?  I want to update the above so the format is like this:
`[ {Name: "Howard Bell", Count: "0"},  {Name: "Matt Blair", Count: "0"}, {Name: "Dave Custer", Count: "0"} ]`

I was trying to set this up by looping through the playerPool array but I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'Name' of undefined

```
let playerPool = [...new Set(array.flat(1))];
let playerObjects = [];

for(let i = 0; i < playerPool.length; i++) {
  playerObjects[i].Name = playerPool[i];
  playerObjects[i].Count = 0;
}
```

My goal is to be able to reference each property individually like this `playerObjects[0].Count` so I can later update the count value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to create the object to which you want to assign the properties.

But you can do it more functional-style with `map`:

```js
let playerPool = ["Howard Bell", "Matt Blair", "Dave Custer"];

let result = playerPool.map(name => ({name, count:0}));

console.log(result);
```

NB: if possible choose camelCase for your property names. There is a common practice to reserve PascalCase for constructor names ("classes").

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```js
let array1 = ["Howard Bell", "Matt Blair", "Dave Custer"];
let array2 = [];

array1.forEach(el => {
  array2.push({Name: el, count: 0});
});

console.log(array2);
```